# Add custom button to edit page of sonata admin bundle

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

As you know, sonata admin bundle comes with three buttons in edit page which are "Add new, update and delete". I can remove delete button with this:

```
protected function configureRoutes(RouteCollection $collection)
{
    $collection
        ->remove('delete')
    ;

}
```

But I want to also add "Send message to User" button in edit of UserAdmin. How can I do this? I can't find any documentation about that in sonata docs.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should hint the parameter if the file is in other namespace, and the add() method should work, but then you have to overwrite the Sonata's CRUD template to be able to display an other button/link.
Additionally you can define the controller and action which will be called.

For example:
src/Acme/DemoBundle/Admin/EntityAdmin.php:

```
protected function configureRoutes(\Sonata\AdminBundle\Route\RouteCollection $collection)
{
    $collection
        ->add('dummy',
            'dummy/{id}',
            array('_controller' => 'AcmeDemoBundle:Default:dummy'),
            array('id' => '\d+')
        )
    ;
}
```

src/Acme/HelloBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php:

```
/**
    @Route("/dummy/{id}", name="dummy",
        requirements={"id" = "\d+"}
    )
    @Template("AcmeDemoBundle:Default:dummy.html.twig")
*/
public function dummyAction($id)
{
    return(array(
        'id' => $id
    ));
}
```

app/Resources/SonataAdminBundle/views/CRUD/base_edit_form.html.twig:

```
{% block form %}
    ...
    {% else %}
        ...
        {% block formactions %}
            ...
            {% else %}
                ...
                {% if admin.id(object) %}
                    ...
                    {% if admin.hasroute('dummy') %}
                        <a class="btn" target="_blank" href="{{ admin.generateObjectUrl('dummy', object) }}">{% trans from 'SonataAdminBundle' %}link_dummy{% endtrans %}</a>
                    {% endif %}
                    ...
```

Comment: is it possible to do the same for embedded admins?

Comment: can't we override the "app/Resources/SonataAdminBundle/views/CRUD/base_edit_form.html.twig" to avoid to change the sonata original files?

Comment: @Lionel by placing files in app/Resources you are overriding them :)