# Adding entity not managed by Sonata Admin Bundle

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata

I have several entities which are managed by Sonata AdminBundle, they are all located in my dashboard, no problem.
I have other entities which are customized and not managed by Sonata AdminBundle, I want to insert them in my dashboard. I read on different forums that we can add content in a different blocks, but no way to find a concrete example.

If you have a solution or some clues to do that, I'm interested :)

Best regards,
Enes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The admin dashboard is a set of block. So you have one block to display managed entities. If you want to display other information or other entities handled by your own mechanism you have to create a new block.

A block is handled by the SonataBlockBundle, the online documentation http://www.sonata-project.org/bundles/block/master/doc/index.html explains how to create a new block. Once the block is created, you can register it to the admin dashboard by editing the admin configuration section: https://github.com/sonata-project/sandbox/blob/2.3/app/config/sonata/sonata_admin.yml#L24-L28

Comment: Great thanks a lot, I find the solution within the links you gave me.

Comment: Nice explanation you can also find here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14113259/how-to-add-custom-link-or-button-to-sonataadminbundle-dashboard-in-symfony2