# Create custom block in Sonata Admin Bundle causes an error

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata, symfony-2.4

### Problem

I used this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/15167450/2910183, but I have a following error when I'm trying open admin dashboard (`http://localhost/app_dev.php/admin/dashboard`). This happens also after cleaning cache.

> ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to load class "AcmeBlockService" from namespace "Acme\ProductBundle\Block" in ~/htdocs/symfony2training/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php line 2216. Do you need to "use" it from another namespace?

Does anybody know where is problem?

### Code

Here is part of my `app/config/config.yml`

```
sonata_block:
    default_contexts: [cms]
    blocks:
        sonata.admin.block.admin_list:
            contexts:   [admin]
        sonata.user.block.menu:     # used to display the menu in profile pages
        sonata.user.block.account:  # used to display menu option (login option)
        acme.block.products:

sonata_admin:
    dashboard:
        blocks:
            # display a dashboard block
            - { position: left, type: acme.block.products }
            - { position: left, type: sonata.admin.block.admin_list }
```

Part of my `src/Acme/ProductBundle/Resources/config/services.yml`

```
services:
    acme.block.products:
        id: acme.block.products
        class: Acme\ProductBundle\Block\ProductsBlockService
        arguments:
            - { name: service, id: templating }
        tags:
            - { name: sonata.block }
```

My `src/Acme/ProductBundle/Document/Products.php` file in :

```
<?php
namespace Acme\ProductBundle\Block;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use Sonata\BlockBundle\Model\BlockInterface;
use Sonata\BlockBundle\Block\BlockContextInterface;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Validator\ErrorElement;
class ProductsBlockService extends BaseBlockService {
    public function getName() {
        return 'Products';
    }
    public function getDefaultSettings() {
        return array();
    }
    public function validateBlock(ErrorElement $errorElement, BlockInterface $block) {
    }
    public function buildEditForm(FormMapper $formMapper, BlockInterface $block) {
    }
    public function execute(BlockInterface $block, Response $response = null) {
        $settings = array_merge($this->getDefaultSettings(), $block->getSettings());
        return $this->renderResponse('AcmeProductBundle:Block:admin_products.html.twig', array(
                'block' => $block,
                'settings' => $settings
        ), $response);
    }
}
```

### Solution

1. I looked into another block (`vendor/sonata-project/user-bundle/Sonata/UserBundle/Block/AccountBlockService.php`) and I realized, that its file name is like class name. So I changed `src/Acme/ProductBundle/Document/Products.php` to `src/Acme/ProductBundle/Document/ProductsBlockService.php`
2. It works, but another error appeared:

   > FatalErrorException: Compile Error: Declaration of Acme\ProductBundle\Block\ProductsBlockService::execute() must be compatible with Sonata\BlockBundle\Block\BlockServiceInterface::execute(Sonata\BlockBundle\Block\BlockContextInterface $blockContext, Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response $response = NULL) in ~/htdocs/symfony2training/src/Acme/ProductBundle/Block/ProductsBlockService.php line 0
3. The solution is written in the error message: *Acme\ProductBundle\Block\ProductsBlockService::execute() must be compatible with Sonata\BlockBundle\Block\BlockServiceInterface::execute()*. So I looked into my helper (*AccountBlockService.php* from 1.), compare `execute()` methods and write my own solution.

So in the end my `src/Acme/ProductBundle/Document/ProductsBlockService.php` file looks as below.

```
<?php
namespace Acme\ProductBundle\Block;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Validator\ErrorElement;
use Sonata\BlockBundle\Block\BaseBlockService;
use Sonata\BlockBundle\Block\BlockContextInterface;
use Sonata\BlockBundle\Model\BlockInterface;
use Sonata\UserBundle\Menu\ProfileMenuBuilder;
use Sonata\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\EngineInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContextInterface;
class ProductsBlockService extends BaseBlockService {
    public function getName() {
        return 'Products';
    }
    public function validateBlock(ErrorElement $errorElement, BlockInterface $block) {
    }
    public function buildEditForm(FormMapper $formMapper, BlockInterface $block) {
    }
    public function setDefaultSettings(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver) {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'template' => 'AcmeProductBundle:Block:admin_products.html.twig',
            'ttl' => 0
        ));
    }
    public function execute(BlockContextInterface $blockContext, Response $response = null) {
        return $this->renderPrivateResponse($blockContext->getTemplate(), array(
                'block' => $blockContext->getBlock(),
                'context' => $blockContext,
            ), $response);
    }
}
```

Comment: I found the solution (question updated).

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer, and accept it, to follow the Q&A standard.