# Create new block in Sonata Admin Bundle causes an error

Tags: php, symfony

I refer this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/15167450/2910183 ,and an error occur:

> Compile Error: Declaration of
>   AppBundle\Block\NewsletterBlockService::execute() must be compatible
>   with
>   Sonata\BlockBundle\Block\BlockServiceInterface::execute(Sonata\BlockBundle\Block\BlockContextInterface
>   $blockContext, Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response $response =
>   NULL)

**Code**

Part of my `app/config/config.yml`

```
sonata_block:
    default_contexts: [cms]
    blocks:
        # enable the SonataAdminBundle block
        sonata.admin.block.admin_list:
            contexts: [admin]
        sonata.user.block.menu: ~    # used to display the menu in profile pages
        sonata.user.block.account: ~ # used to display menu option (login option)
        sonata.block.service.text: ~
        sonata.block.service.rss: ~
        sonata.block.service.newsletter: ~

sonata_admin:
    dashboard:
        blocks:
            -
                position: left
                type: sonata.admin.block.admin_list
                settings:
                    groups: [default, app.admin.group.content]
            -
                position: right
                type: sonata.admin.block.admin_list
                settings:
                   groups: [default]
            - { position: left, type: sonata.block.service.newsletter}
```

**Part of my** `/private/var/www/learning_sonata/app/config/services.yml`

```
sonata.block.service.newsletter:
        class: AppBundle\Block\NewsletterBlockService
        arguments: [ "sonata.block.service.newsletter", @templating ]
        tags:
            - { name: sonata.block }
```

**My** `/private/var/www/learning_sonata/src/AppBundle/Block/NewsletterBlockService.php`

```
namespace AppBundle\Block;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

use Sonata\BlockBundle\Model\BlockInterface;
use Sonata\BlockBundle\Block\BlockContextInterface;
use Sonata\BlockBundle\Block\BlockContext;

use Sonata\BlockBundle\Block\BlockServiceInterface;

use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;
use Sonata\CoreBundle\Validator\ErrorElement;
use Sonata\BlockBundle\Block\BaseBlockService;


//use Sonata\BlockBundle\Block;

class NewsletterBlockService extends BaseBlockService
{
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'My Newsletter';
    }

    public function getDefaultSettings()
    {
        return array();
    }

    public function validateBlock(ErrorElement $errorElement, BlockInterface $block)
    {
    }

    public function buildEditForm(FormMapper $formMapper, BlockInterface $block)
    {
    }

    public function execute(BlockInterface $block, Response $response = null)
    {
        // merge settings
        $settings = array_merge($this->getDefaultSettings(), $block->getSettings());

        return $this->renderResponse('InstitutoStoricoNewsletterBundle:Block:block_my_newsletter.html.twig', array(
            'block'     => $block,
            'settings'  => $settings
        ), $response);
    }
}
```

Thanks devilcius!

I refer your answer,clear the error above,but new erro occur:

> Method "id" for object "Sonata\BlockBundle\Block\BlockContext" does
>   not exist in SonataBlockBundle:Block:block_base.html.twig at line 11

**File path** `vendor/sonata-project/block-bundle/Resources/views/Block/block_base.html.twig`

```
<div id="cms-block-{{ block.id }}" class="cms-block cms-block-element">
    {% block block %}EMPTY CONTENT{% endblock %}
</div>
```

**Sonata Version**

```
sonata-project/admin-bundle              3.1.0   The missing Symfony Admin ...
sonata-project/block-bundle              3.0.0   Symfony SonataBlockBundle
sonata-project/cache                     1.0.7   Cache library
sonata-project/core-bundle               3.0.0   Symfony SonataCoreBundle
sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle 3.0.1   Symfony Sonata / Integrate...
sonata-project/exporter                  1.4.1   Lightweight Exporter library
```

I read this [resource](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataBlockBundle/issues/142),it said it's the version pro.

Could u give some idea,guys?

Answer (score 0):

You're not implementing the method signature when extending BaseBlockService.

```
use Sonata\BlockBundle\Block\BlockContextInterface;

public function execute(BlockContextInterface $blockContext, Response $response = null)
{    
    return $this->renderResponse('InstitutoStoricoNewsletterBundle:Block:block_my_newsletter.html.twig', array(
        'block'     => $blockContext->getBlock(),
        'settings'  => $blockContext->getSettings()
    ), $response);
}
```

Comment: Awesome,but an error occur,I have update my question above. @devilcius

Comment: Which versions of sonata* are you using (`composer show | grep sonata`)?