# how to create new action in sonata admin

Tags: symfony, action, sonata-admin

i use sonata admin with symfony2.4. i have two entities exam and student with Many To Many relation , what i want is when i add a new exam, a new button created that shows me the list of student should participate in the exam. in configureField form i have these buttons:
Create, Create and return to list, Create and add

when i click the button create to add a new exam, these are buttons created by sonata:

Update, Update and close, Delete.
i want to add a new button 'students list' to these buttons, is it possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add custom button to edit page of sonata admin bundle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11725476/add-custom-button-to-edit-page-of-sonata-admin-bundle)

Comment: Thanks, but i have not understand the code, what is id??? also i want that the liste of students be shown like default sonata show list(i do not want to create my own template). how to do it?

Comment: i tried the code but  when i click on the created button i got this error message:The controller must return a response (Array(id => 14) given). i put my query in the controller function right?

Comment: You need to return a response (with template) not a result from a query...

Comment: public function listeStudentAction($id)
{
    return(array(
        'id' => $id
    ));
}this is the code i used. how to return the template that shows the result of my query?